# On which stack exchange site should I ask this question?

Tags: discussion, support, allowed-topics, asking-questions, community

Where should I ask [Language and Sociology](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/67361/language-and-sociology/67367#67367)?

Comment: If you don't know the word "intuitive" at all, then read a dictionary - there is no site where that's an allowed question. If you want clarity for that answer, then ask the author directly to clarify.

Comment: I do not fail to understand the individual word as an entry in a dictionary.https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/intuitive I fail to understand the word in the specific context.

Answer (score 2):

## [SE.EnglishLanguageLearners](https://ell.stackexchange.com).

> I fail to understand what intuitive means on "what’s on- and off-topic is not always intuitive".

You can ask questions about basic English at the [English Language Learners site](https://ell.stackexchange.com).  This site is for people who are learning English.

For example, you might post a new question titled:

> What does "what’s on- and off-topic is not always intuitive" mean?

, with the body of the question as:

> I saw a comment that said
>
> > what’s on- and off-topic is not always intuitive
>
> What does this mean?

Comment: I do not fail to understand the individual word as an entry in a https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/intuitive I fail to understand the word in the specific context. I am confident of my command of the English language I have a C2 since age 14(8 years and a half since then) and through ESP in Economics, Law, Medicine I have evolved it to a great extend due to extensive paper reading to support my studies and extensive travelling abroad. My assesment in all skills is Reading exceptional, Use of English exceptional, Listening very good, Speaking very good, Writing good.

Comment: Probably I am not as idiomatic as a native speaker but my pedantic nature(I am a foreign user so I somehow need to make up for the lack of idiomaticity), my commitment to my studies and all my learning activities more than make up for the lack of idiomaticity.

Comment: Last but not least this is a meta question I wanted to discuss a question I already asked on the main site and it was not that well received. https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/67361/language-and-sociology/67367 My question does not address the fact I do not understand intuitive in that context(clear instead would be much better understood). My question addresses the problem that I do not know where to ask the question that was off-topic here.

Comment: @GeorgeNtoulos If I might be blunt, I get the feeling that your ego is getting in the way.  You have a simple misunderstanding about basic English, so you should ask about it at the StackExchange site devoted to basic English.  I appreciate that you self-identify as a fluent, articulate English speaker, but.. I mean, honestly, you're not.  Your English is actually pretty bad.  Which I don't say to be mean, just, objectively speaking, these are questions you should be asking at SE.EnglishLanguageLearners, despite your personal preference to perceive them as more nuanced than that.

Comment: Then https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/67361/language-and-sociology/67367 belongs to https://ell.stackexchange.com/? Because that is my question what does intuitive mean in the given context is trivial. The question what very specific where should I ask X question.

Comment: @GeorgeNtoulos If your question was just **"_Could someone systematically, methodologically, organisedly research Sociology, Civilisation, Culture through Language?_"**, then the answer's basically just "_Yes_".  Did you mean to ask specifically how a specific question about society can be researched through examination of some aspect of language, or...?

Comment: Please pardon me I meant to ask whether there were any such research papers too. And request to be provided with some of them. It was my mistake. I do not know if adding it though would suddenly make it on topic in Philosophy. There is no Sociology stack exchange.

Comment: @GeorgeNtoulos There're entire journals devoted to fields like the [sociology of language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sociology_of_language), e.g. [the _International Journal of the Sociology of Language_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Journal_of_the_Sociology_of_Language).  For a StackExchange question, you'll probably want to ask something more specific.

Comment: These particulal feats of diverse languages. Japanese asking for pardon when others would thank. Greeks introducing T-V distinction(mid 19-century and keeping it for almost 2 centuries) while most others lost it. English weakening Master. Most languages using some word derived from Senex. Herr(it simply sounds similar to Sir and has the same meaning), Signore,Senhor, Sir, Señor, Monsieur instead of a word derived for Dominus or Magister from Mangus like the unweakened Master does. Asking for permission instead of asking for pardon.

Comment: @GeorgeNtoulos It sounds like you might be trying to post an observation in hopes of sparking a discussion about it, which would seem more appropriate for a discussion forum.  Here at StackExchange, you'll want to ask a clear question about a specific thing that can be answered.

Comment: Please define "specific". Do you mean (In Logic) Denoting a proposition in which something is asserted of some but not all of a class.
Contrasted with universal. In that case I think particular would be more appropriate. Specific is contrasted with Abstractive. I think loss of generality is bad. Sure from a Reductionist perspective we need to remove any details(remove cases) so as to learn anything. But I do not think a single particular case would be pedagogic either.

Comment: I do not want to spark a discussion on the observations. I want a clear-cut explanation of the observations. I observe X. I ask why does X happen. How did X happen(the process) and What is X(what happened) are some times what I am asking. But I am not asking about any single particular case but the totallity. Aren't there any papers that do not deal with a partical case but the totallity of the differences?

Comment: @GeorgeNtoulos I suggest that you try asking simpler questions to practice communication.  Once your communication skills improve, you'll probably find it easier to ask about more involved topics.  Even for native English speakers, it can take a while to learn how to form good questions at StackExchange.

Comment: The language is only a tool. You may be an Oxford valedictorian(with a Bachelors', Masters',PhD, a teaching habilitation all in English Language and in Oxford and a valedictorian in all off them) and not be as good in communicating in the English language as some random semi-illiterate bloke in some village. A screw driver does not help one as much as the existance of arms, teeth,lips, legs or the experience and need to drive in a screw. Good Use of English does not imply Good Questions and likewise a Bad Question does not imply Poor Use of English. There are neurodevelopmental disorders etc.

Comment: Communication uses language it does not identify with language. They are not 2 identical things or the other side of the same coin. There are many factors to communication. Including some social, biological, cognitive, behavioral factors.

Answer (score 2):

I voted to close [the question](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/67361/29944) because I could not tell what you were trying to ask. To help understand why, consider the current first sentence:

> Could someone systematically, methodologically, organisedly research Sociology, Civilisation, Culture through Language?

If I read this literally, the question is very broad. You seem to be asking people to do this research on the spot. However, then I assumed what you really meant was the following:

> Is it possible for a researcher to scientifically study sociology, civilization and culture through language?

That seems to be what people actually do. So it would be possible, but then there must be more to this.  However, I couldn't find a specific question.

I recommend rewriting this around a specific question you have in mind. Use a reference you can cite (preferably available online) to provide context.  That reference would make the question even more specific.

I don't think this has any better chance of being accepted on any other site if the issue is clarity or being too broad.

Comment: If I tried to restrict it I would end up with a question that is stricly of topic(instead of too broad, vague or ambiguous). If I asked why did the English language relinquish/forsake T-V so Early while others just recently introduced it it would be a question for English/Linguistics and not Sociology. My question is more like How was the English society so as to abolish so quickly T-V? Does society explain the divergence in the use of Languages and are there any references? Is it the optimum approach to explain the divergence?

Comment: @GeorgeNtoulos I don't know what "T-V" is, so a reference to that concept would be an opportunity to provide context. Find a philosopher who discusses T-V and that helps move the question to philosophy rather than sociology. To avoid it being confused with linguistics find tags with other posts that deal with similar issues. Finally, make sure the question can be answered briefly without using much personal opinion. This is a question-answer site not a blog for discussing topics.

Comment: I should probably use the correct term https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%E2%80%93V_distinction. Good answers are usually long . Guidelines for Great Subjective Questions. https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243200/how-to-ask-a-good-subjective-question It is not Physics Physics deals with Physical Quantities(which are physical entities) they have an inherent nature. A million people may measure the same physical quantity and they should come up with the exact same result(Save for Statistical Mistakes in the Measurement).

Comment: That is what Metrology the science of measurement studies. It guarantees that everyone should measure the same way(the define the proper way to measure). Language and Society is more of an idea than a thing(res) a physical entity. Philosophy studies ideas not physical entities. I can not ask something very pragmatic on Philosophy not expect short answers.

Comment: @GeorgeNtoulos It is difficult to ask a good question on these SE sites. However, being able to ask such a question clarifies parts of the puzzle that can be used in the larger area of interest. Find out specific information that people know through questions and answers and then use that to formulate a better understanding. Sometimes a question asking for references may be specific enough to attract useful answers.